# how to check if input type is radio using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to handle html elements differently based on their type.

Using jquery, how do I check to see if an input type is a radio button?

I've tried:

```
if ($('#myElement').is(':radio')) {
    ....//code here
}
```

and

```
if ($('#myElement').is("input[type='radio']")) {
    ....//code here
}
```

Neither of these worked. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
if ($('#myElement').is(':radio')) {
    ....//code here
}
```

works, but my radio buttons don't have the id attribute, they only have a name attribute, which is why it did not work.

I changed my code to:

```
if ($('input[name=' + myElement + ']').is(":radio")) {
    ....//code here
}
```

Comment: if you solved your own problem you should have posted it as an answer and chosen it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

That should work as long as the elements are loaded.

```
// Ensure the DOM is ready
$(function() {
    if ($('#myElement').is(':radio')) {
        //code here
    }
});
```

If you're assigning handlers based on type, another approach would be to use `.filter()`.

```
$(function() {
    var el = $('#myElement');
    el.filter(':radio').change(function() {
        //code here
    });

    el.filter(':checkbox').change(function() {
        // other code here
    });
});
```

If it doesn't pass the `filter()`, the handler won't be assigned.

Comment: Unfortunately is(':radio') returns true for a checkbox as well as a radio button, so might be best to .attr('type') =='radio' instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
if($('#my-element').attr('type') == 'radio')
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work you can try to use filter this way instead

```
if ($('#myElement').filter(':radio').size() > 0) {
    ....//code here
}
and

if ($('#myElement').filter("input[type='radio']").size() > 0) {
    ....//code here
}
```

Or

```
$('#myElement:radio').each(function() {
        ....//code here
});
```

**Udate:** Are you also sure that the id is unique in the page? If you want to select more as 1 element you can use a class instead.